# Powershell printing invalid characters when there are ascent characters in the data

Tags: powershell, invalid-characters

I am having data in the database. Using Powershell Invoke-RestMethod, I am trying to fetch the data. When I am trying to save the output to a Variable and print it, it is showing me invalid characters (not same as Original).

Below is the Data stored in the database

```
GCM â€“ PLPD Resource RW
```

Here's my code

```
$output=Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $WebServiceURL -Body $json -ContentType "Application/json"
Write-Host $output.OutputObject.SUBROOT
```

Below is my Output with Invalid Characters

```
@{SecurityGroupName=GCM Ã¢â‚¬â€œ PLPD Resource RW}
```

Comment: I can only guess here. But maybe `-ContentType` should be `'Application/json; charset=utf-8'`. If there is an issue with `$body`, that may need to be converted to `UTF8` and/or byte format as well.

Comment: Here's a link with some google juice:  https://powershell.org/forums/topic/character-encoding-with-invoke-restmethod/

Comment: Also, if your code lies within a script or module file, ensure the file is encoded as UTF-8.  And it might be worthwhile to check the `$OutputEncoding` preference variable in your PowerShell host console too.  If you need to change it, check `[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncodings()` for available options.  For example, for UTF-8, the command would be: `$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(65001)`